# Get data from three models with relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent-relationship

I have three models :

Serie ($id)

```
public function saisons() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Season::class);
}

public function episodes() 
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Episode::class, Season::class);
}
```

Season ($serie_id)

```
public function serie()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Serie::class);
}

public function episodes() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(Episode::class);
}
```

Episode ($season_id)

```
public function season()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Season::class);
}

public function serie()
{
    return $this->BelongsToThrough(Serie::class, Season::class);
}
```

I would like to show one specific season from a serie with the episodes associated

My view

```
<h1 class="title">{{$serie->seasons->number}}</h1>


@foreach ($serie->seasons->episodes as $episode)

        <div class="row">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="col">
       {{$episode->number}}
       <a href="{{route('episodes.show', $episode->id)}}">{{$episode->name}}</a>



        @if(isset($episode->programmation->date))

            {{$episode->programmation->date}}

        @endif
       @if (($episode->season_finale) == '0')
            Non
            @elseif (($episode->season_finale) == '1')
            Oui
            @endif

        @foreach ($episode->chaines as $chaine)
                   {{$chaine->name}}

            @endforeach
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

Route

```
Route::get('/serie/{serie}/saison/{season}', 'Front\SaisonController@show')->name('saison.show');
```

For my url, I choose to show the number of the saison and not the id and I think that's the problem.

How can I do that in a proper way ?

Comment: You don't need season connected to serie. You just episode <-> season logic. You will get serie's sesons over episodes. It would be easier way.

Comment: Ok but how do I get the right season on my view ?

Comment: I am talking about DB logic. Probably good way would be to have `season` column in `episodes` table because it is crucial part of episode entity. But if you need to go with third seasons table something like [this](https://3v4l.org/IeXPl). Again, try to add `episodes`.`season` field and use just `Serie` and `Episode` models.

Comment: I tried this and it gives me this error : 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `episodes` where exists (select * from `serie` inner join `season` on `season`.`serie_id` = `serie`.`id` where `season`.`id` = `episodes`.`season_id` and (`id` = 1)) and exists (select * from `season` where `episodes`.`season_id` = `season`.`id` and (`season` = 2)))

I'm rather new to Laravel and php in general and it's very complex to me, i'm not sure how to do it even with your explication :(

Comment: Fixed [that](https://3v4l.org/G14S3) one.

Comment: The larger problem is to retrieve the season with the number and not the id because if I tried to get the season with the id, it gives me a 404

Comment: I am not sure I can help further with this since this requires DB restructuring. I gave my best for 3 tables structure but you will need to go through relations in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships) and find some articles/videos online to connect the dots of what I proposed here.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, someone help me to find the right answer :

```
     $serie = Serie::findOrFail($serie);
     $season =  Season::where('serie_id', $serie->id)->where('season.number', $season)->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach can help you.

```
$serie = Serie::where('id',$id)->with('seasons'=>function($query) use ($season_id) {
            $query->where('season_id',$season_id)->with('episodes')->get();
    })->get();
```

Comment: I have an error : Trying to get property 'number' of non-object